# If $a^HUa=0$ for all $a$, can we conclude that $U=0$?

Tags: matrices

I have the following equation:
$a^HUa=0$
where '$a$' can be any arbitrary vector and $U$ is a matrix ($H$ means Hermitian). Can we conclude that $U=0$? Any reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can conclude that $U$ needs to be a square matrix for the involved expression to make sense.  Let $U$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.

$$
\text{ the $i$th component of vector $Ua$: } (Ua)_i = \sum_{k=1}^n U_{ik}a_{k}.  
$$

and similarly
$$
\begin{align*}
 a^HUa &= \sum_{j = 1}^n a^H_{j} (Ua)_j \\
&= \sum_{j} \sum_{k} a_j^*U_{jk}a_k
\end{align*}
$$

Let $a_j = \delta_{r,j}$, which is $1$ only index $r$ and zero elsewhere.  Then, 
$$
  a^HUa = 0 = U_{rr}
$$
So you can conclude that the diagonal of $U$ is zero.

Letting $a_j = (1, 0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0)$ (a $1$ in the $s$ and $t$th places).

Then you have $U_{st} + U_{ts} = 0$.  So the matrix is anti-symmetric.

Lets try the same thing with $i$ and $1$.  Then we have
$$
(-i)U_{st} + iU_{ts} = 0
$$

Thus the off-diagonal elements are anti-symmetric and equal, hence *zero*.  QED